# Using C# Expression Trees, can I create an anonymous to typed object map?

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

This is on a data tier so performance is extremely important.  Otherwise I would use Automapper.  If it were an IDBConnection I'd use Dapper.

I'd like to take the simple authoring of an anonymous object to a POCO and express it using compiled expressions.

**Code**

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar{get;set;}
    public string Baz{get;set;}
}

public void doStuff()
{
     var obj = new{Bar= "My Name, Baz = "Some other data"};

     //can I recreate this assignment to foo using expressions?
     var foo = new Foo{
         Bar = obj.Bar,
         Baz = obj.Baz
     }
}
```

**(Incomplete) So far I have...**

```
var props = o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)

    foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    var targetProp = typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name);
                    var targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "target");
                    var valueExp = Expression.Parameter(prop.PropertyType, "property");



                    var propExp = Expression.Property(targetExp, targetProp);
                    var assignExp = Expression.Assign(propExp, valueExp);

                    var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, object>>(assignExp, targetExp, valueExp).Compile();
                }
```

**Current Issues**

1. How do I combine the setters into a return compiled delegate?
2. How can I create the Lambda[Action] generic type when I'm looping over the properties?

Thanks for any and all input.

Comment: It's not clear what the context is here - is this already a generic method accepting the anonymous type as the type argument, and `typeof(Foo)` as a parameter?

Comment: As an aside, the simplest way to find out what something *like* this does is to just write a lambda expression compiling to an expression tree and then decompile it.

Comment: First part: the method would be like 'T MapFrom<T,object>(object obj)' where the object is guaranteed to always be the same anonymous object.

Second part: great idea.  I'll try that now.

Comment: Why would you not create the mapping delegate once, then reuse it?

Comment: I would.  I just left that part out of it. Reusing it is no problem...Creating it is the issue.

Comment: So that wouldn't actually be the signature... It's a lot easier for us to help you with accurate context.

Comment: Fair enough...let me get a more complete picture up there.

Comment: Using a List<> object will help. public class Foo
{
    public string Bar{get;set;}
    public string Baz{get;set;}
    public List<Foo> children {get;set;}
}

Comment: Definitely try the FastMapper/Mapster. They generate a dynamic IL to map objects so that the performance is an order of magnitude better than the Automapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Tests
{
    public static class Utils
    {
        public static Func<TInput, TOutput> CreateMapFunc<TInput, TOutput>()
        {
            var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInput), "source");
            var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(TOutput)),
                source.Type.GetProperties().Select(p => Expression.Bind(typeof(TOutput).GetProperty(p.Name), Expression.Property(source, p))));
            var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, TOutput>>(body, source);
            return expr.Compile();
        }
    }
    public static class MapFunc<TInput, TOutput>
    {
        public static readonly Func<TInput, TOutput> Instance = Utils.CreateMapFunc<TInput, TOutput>();
    }
    public struct Unit<T>
    {
        public readonly T Value;
        public Unit(T value) { Value = value; }
        public U MapTo<U>() { return MapFunc<T, U>.Instance(Value); }
    }
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Unit<T> Unit<T>(this T source) { return new Unit<T>(source); }
    }
    // Test
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
        public string Baz { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = new { Bar = "My Name", Baz = "Some other data" };
            //var foo = new Foo { Bar = obj.Bar, Baz = obj.Baz };
            var foo = obj.Unit().MapTo<Foo>();
        }
    }
}
```

In case someone is interesting how it works:

The main part is the `CreateMapFunc` function which builds and compiles a lambda expression by using `MemberInitExpression`. It really should be a private function inside the `MapFunc<TInput, TOutput>` class - I've put it in a separate class just to show the answer of the original question.

`MapFunc<TInput, TOutput>` class is a singleton and acts as a cache for the compiled function delegates.

`Unit<T>` acts as intermediator and (along with the extension method) is needed to allow inferring the type of the passed anonymous object and specifying only the target type.

Comment: Nice!  This was the usage I was hoping for.